# What is the best way for implementing rich text support in an Android application?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, android-edittext, spannablestring

I want to make a notes app. However, the hardest part to even figure out for me is how to add rich text support to it.

For example, I want the user to be able to select some text, press the bold button and it should toggle the selected text to bold (Make it bold if it is a normal text and make it normal if it is bold, like in Word or Google Docs).

My idea is supporting as much formats as possible. The ones I have in mind are:

- bold
- italics
- underline
- strikethrough
- left alignment
- center alignment
- right alignment
- justified alignment
- highliting(background color)
- text color
- bulleted lists

I thought about using *SpannableStrings*, and for now, it's worked well with the following code:

```
editText.text.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), editText.selectionStart, editText.selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

But the issue would be toggling the selection without messing up other styles (Like when toggling the bold style, do not affect italics, etc),as for now, the code above only makes them bold, but not back to normal.

Also, I do not know how could I be saving them, if converting it to a String (if it is even possible) or directly storing the object with the help of the *Gson library*.

The other alternative I thought of was using *Html tags*, as it would be easy just to save the whole thing as a String, but the downside comes to applying the effect itself, because I would have to add the html tags to the text and that could cause issues.

I am using Kotlin and Room. What would you recommend me to do?

Comment: I think you should look into `SpannableString`.

Answer (score 1):

well you will definitely need some logic behind this. Probably if I were you, I would create an enum with all the features you want to use (for example BOLD, ITALIC, UNDERLINE ...) and each time user selects part of the text, I would store the list containing tuple of start/end text indexes which define the text selection as well as style for it. Unfortunately each time you want to set a new style, you will need to reload the spannable string and set it on the TextView again. Example would look like this:

```
data class StyleSelection(
    val selection: Pair<Int, Int>,
    val style: Style
)
...
styleSelections.add(StyleSelection(pairOf(x, y), Style.BOLD))
...
create SpannableString from the StyleSelection objects
```